# Как правильно пользоваться функцией рандом в php?

Tags: php, случайные-числа

Добрый день. Учу пхп, столкнулся с такой проблемой: есть скрипт, который генерирует 1 случайное число. Но на сервере время обновляется раз в несколько секунд, поэтому если несколько раз быстро перевыполнить скрипт, генератор генерит одно и то же число. Как мне обойти эту проблему?

Comment: Какой функцией генерируете чистло? Вообще https://habrahabr.ru/company/mailru/blog/352446/ Отличная статья на тему.

Comment: используйте mt_rand

Comment: Используйте PHP 7+ и функцию **random_int()** http://php.net/manual/ru/function.random-int.php

Answer (score 1):

`mt_rand()` самая проверенная и надежная функция, котороя возвращает псевдорандомное число, никак не зависит от сервера и из-за сервера генерировать одинаковые числа не может, используйте эту функцию и будет вам **почти** настоящий рандома. 
Можете так-же использовать более современную функцию `random_int`, но там есть свои ньюансы, которых нет у первой функции.

Comment: Ну не знаю, я как раз её и использую... Просто числа обновляются раз в 2 секунды, то есть если быстро обновить страницу, или зайти одновременно с 2-х компов, числа одинаковые...

Comment: Вы можете предоставить нам код? Дело в том что сложно что-то сказать, не наблюдая хотя бы чуть кода.

Comment: та банальный echo mt_rand(); 
Если быстро обновлять страницу, то числа одинаковые рандомятся

Comment: Мне кажется, дело не в функции, а в сервере, может быть просто ваш сервер настроен так, что если первый коннект ещё не завершился, при повторном коннекте скрипт не перезапускается, а отдаётся тот же результат. Могу попробовать подсказать вам, если вы после вывода рандомного числа хотите чтобы скрипт завершился поставьте после вывода рандома функцию `exit()`, таким образом каждый раз по идее будет уникальное значение.

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = [];
function getRandom($min = 0, $max = 9999, $try = 0) use ($array)
{
   $int = mt_rand($min, $max);

   if (in_array($int, $array) || $try > 5) {
       return getRandom($min, $max, ++$try);
   }

   return $int;
}
```

вместо `$array` можно брать/хранить числа в базе